# Averaging Nested Values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i was looking for a way to sum and to average 'nested values' in that document. I'm interested in averaging the number of kids of a user. 
Those lines gave me a results of 0 .

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
   {
$group: {
    _id: "id",
    Mean: {
        $avg: "$data.details.MemberDetails.numberOfKids"
    }
  }
}])
```

I have read some question here in stackoverflow, and the problem that my data is located in an object that's located in an array which is located in an object 
This is how the data looks like. 
Any help will be useful.
Thanks.

```
 /* 1 */
{
>     "_id" : "160b2af1fdf06daf3",
>     "userId" : "943af0fa65da28a4",
>     "data" : {
>         "details" : [ 
>               {
>                 "MemberDetails" : {
>                   
>                         "numberOfKids" : 3,
>                         "Statuse" : "married",
>                 
>                     },
>                     "MemberDescroption" : {
>                         "hight" : 1.80,
>                         "wight" : 85,
>                     }
>                 }
>               ]
>              }
> 
> }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten the array first before grouping the documents, use the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** pipeline operator:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$data.details" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "id",
            "Mean": {
                "$avg": "$data.details.MemberDetails.numberOfKids"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the quick respond.
I'm getteing the next error ,
 "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$uniwnd'",

Comment: @NatiBarchilon Thanks for noticing the typo; had written `'$uniwnd'` instead of `'$unwind'`. Try again and don't forget to check the documentation on [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind).

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it !
so for summing i would do the same , thanks again.